# store values from Add & Remove Select Lists

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, forms, html-select

I have use this [This to make add/remove select list](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/create-add-remove-select-lists-using-jquery/)

```
<form action="home.php?action=test" method="post" id="myform" name="myform" onsubmit="ValidatePageForm()">
<fieldset>
<select name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple size="5">
<option value="1">Item 1</option>
<option value="2">Item 2</option>
<option value="3">Item 3</option>
<option value="4">Item 4</option>
</select>
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a>
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</a>
<select name="selectto" id="select-to" multiple size="5">
<option value="5">Item 5</option>
<option value="6">Item 6</option>
<option value="7">Item 7</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

using below script i can see values of selected options

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidatePageForm()
{
$('#select-to option').each(function(){
alert($(this).val());
});
}
</script>
```

But how can i take these values and store them in database??
because when i submit i dont get see data in post dump.

any help regarding this please.

Thanks,
Shahzad

Comment: can you show your php code

Comment: there is no PHP code yet.
once i get value in post dump then i think it is easy to store in database.

the problem is i can alert the values but how to get them and store them in variable ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="home.php?action=test" method="post" id="myform" name="myform" onsubmit="ValidatePageForm()">
<fieldset>
<select name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple size="5">
<option value="1">Item 1</option>
<option value="2">Item 2</option>
<option value="3">Item 3</option>
<option value="4">Item 4</option>
</select>
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a>
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</a>
<select name="selectto[]" id="select-to" multiple size="5"><!--declare name as array-->
<option value="5">Item 5</option>
<option value="6">Item 6</option>
<option value="7">Item 7</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Since you are trying to get multiple values , first of all you need to declare your element as array, and then you can get these values in php like this

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['selectto'])){
        $selecto = $_POST['selectto'];
        foreach($selecto as $selecto_vals)
             echo $selecto_vals;           
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: I have tried this but the problem is
i have two select box what ever user want to select from (selectfrom) they will select those options and click add so that those option will move to select box (selectto)

and even after declaring element as array form doesnt post this element as at the time if submit options are not selected.

what i want is what ever option are in selectto get those option and store them.